# Sorting multidimensional arrays in actionscript

Tags: sorting, multidimensional-array, actionscript

At the moment I am trying to convert a 16 by 4 array into a 16 by 2 array. I am doing this by summing the 4 rows and then assigning the row value as the key (hence fitness[0,0] could be [x,0] and fitness[1,0] would be [y,1]) after this I want to sort the fitness array by the first column (the x and y in my example) using the sortOn method. For some reason this is not working. Is there any suggestion as to what is wrong with my code?

```
var i = int;
var j = int;
var temp = int;
var sum = int;
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i <16; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        temp = genotype[i][j];
        sum = sum + temp;
    }
    fitness[i] = [sum,i];
    sum = 0;
}

fitness.sortOn("0");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that [`sortOn()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn()) sorts the elements in an array according to properties in the array. The array should have the following characteristics:

1. The array is an indexed array, not an associative array.
2. Each element of the array holds an [object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) with one or more properties.
3. All of the objects have at least **one property in common**, the values of which can be used to sort the array.

So then, this is an array:

`var a:Array = ["a", "b", "c"]`

This is an object (a.k.a. Associative Array):

`var o:Object = {"name":"Tom", "age":21, "single":true}`

And this is the type of structure that the `sortOn()` method applies to:

```
var a:Array = [
    {"name":"Tom", "age":21, "single":true},
    {"name":"Dick", "age":36, "single":false},
    {"name":"Harry", "age":27, "single":true}
]
```

Also, when you declare a variable the pattern is `NAME:TYPE = VALUE`, and not `NAME = TYPE`

Here is the appropriate code.  You've added `print()` function which traces out the contents of an array so that you can see the before and after.

```
/* --- Code that wasn't provided --- */
// This creates the data so we can test sorting it.

var genotype:Array = [];
for (var r:int = 0; r < 16; r++) {
    var row:Array = [];
    for (var c:int = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        row.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    }
    genotype.push(row)
}

var fitness:Array = [];

/* --- Modified Original Code --- */
// Loop through the genotype, and create entries in fitness with the sum and index
for (var i:int = 0; i < genotype.length; i++) {
    fitness[i] = {"sum":sumArray(genotype[i]), "index":i};
}

function sumArray(a:Array):Number {
    // This simply adds up the total values in an array.
    var sum:int = 0;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

fitness.sortOn("sum", Array.NUMERIC);  // Sort on the sum property, numerically ascending.


// To sort the original data, I'm going to place it into a new array.
var newGeno:Array = [];
i = 0;
for each (var entry:Object in fitness) {
    newGeno[i] = genotype[entry.index];
    i++;
}

/* If you want, you can replace the original, simply add...
    genotype = newGeno;
*/

trace("--- GENOTYPE ---")
print(genotype);

trace("--- NEW GENO ---")
print(newGeno);

function print(a:Array, prefix:String = ""):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] is Array) {
            trace(prefix + i + ": [Array] " + sumArray(a[i]));
            print(a[i], prefix + "    ");
        } else {
            trace(prefix + i + ": " + a[i])
        }
    }
}
```